# Trailing comma error with prop typing in Vue.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

I'm using Typescript with Vue. I want to add typing for my props but lint gives me an error because of the trailing comma. In this case:

```
  21:6  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

   9 |       type: Object,
  10 |       required: true
> 11 |     } as PropOptions<MenuItem[]>,
     |       ^
  12 |   },
  13 |   data: () => ({}),
  14 | })
```

Code:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue, { PropOptions } from 'vue'
import { MenuItem } from '~/types/data'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'UiSubmenu',
  props: {
    submenuProp: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    } as PropOptions<MenuItem[]>,
  },
  data: () => ({}),
})
</script>
```

I've tried to disabled the comma-dangle rule but no results.

Comment: can you wrap it in `()`

Comment: tried, but no results too

Comment: can you show the whole snippet?

Comment: @depperm I've edited my post.

Comment: Have a look: https://frontendsociety.com/using-a-typescript-interfaces-and-types-as-a-prop-type-in-vuejs-508ab3f83480

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem is the trailing comma. If you remove it, ts still complains about the type assertion.

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
const myProp: MyCustomType = {
  default: "hello",
  type: String
};

export default {
  name: "App",
  props: {
    myProp,
  },
  // ...
};
```

Comment: Looks like it's my only option right now so thanks for help.

Comment: Maybe you could use Vue.extend generic definitions to specify all prop types: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/468c323af1f7e296886d5df1a05d3793f60f9e8f/types/vue.d.ts#L89 but i think it's not worth it. Composition api will probably make thinks like that a lot easier

Comment: Yes you should.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your typescript syntax.
You must type your props with a function that returns the right type.

Like that:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue, { PropOptions } from 'vue'
import { MenuItem } from '~/types/data'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'UiSubmenu',
  props: {
    submenuProp: {
      type: Object as () => PropOptions<MenuItem[]>,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data: () => ({}),
})
</script>
```

And this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ],
      "@tests/*": [
        "tests/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

And this is my tslint.json

```
{
  "defaultSeverity": "warning",
  "extends": [
    "tslint:recommended"
  ],
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "rules": {
    "quotemark": [true, "single"],
    "indent": [true, "spaces", 2],
    "semicolon": [true, "never"],
    "eofline": true,
    "interface-name": false,
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "newline-before-return": true,
    "no-consecutive-blank-lines": true,
    "arrow-parens": [true, "ban-single-arg-parens"],
    "no-bitwise": false,
    "variable-name": {
      "options": [
        "ban-keywords",
        "check-format",
        "allow-leading-underscore",
        "allow-pascal-case"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not change anything, this is the same situation therefore with another nested object. Anyway, I still have the same issue.

Comment: Have you got any other component with typescript which working?

Comment: It's the first project component with typing so I can't answer this question :)

Comment: Is it your first component in this project with typescript?

Comment: I just edit my commit with my tslint file and typescript config.
I hope this could be helpful.